# Eclipse not Finding Library for Executable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, runtime, executable

I have a java project with a user library that can be read from the IDE at runtime without any problem. When I export the project to an executable jar, the program no longer finds the library. Specifically,

```
try {
        System.loadLibrary("DPJava64");

    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    }
```

The program runs fine from the IDE, but I get the error message when I try to run the executable jar. The executable jar says that it expects an absolute path.

Comment: A library contained in a JAR cannot be loaded. Either having it outside the JAR or having some Java code that extract it first and then load it from the location where it was extracted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass library as classpath parameter using `-cp` parameter, alternatively if you are using maven you can build [uber jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

[Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)